# Реакция на нажатие по невидимому спрайту в библиотеке SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml, click, экран, спрайт

В окне приложения есть несколько спрайтов в разных местах - все они скрыты.
При нажатии на эти спрайты, происходит взаимодействие с ними, не смотря на то, что они скрыты.
То есть, нажимая на пустое место экрана, они активны.
Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: что значит скрыты?

Comment: Это значит, что они не отрисовываются на экране. Не всегда ведь нужны кнопки меню.

Comment: Укажите их взаимодействие только тогда когда эти спрайты отображаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из возможных способов это временная блокировка и разблокировка 
взаимодействия мыши с невидимым спрайтом, через условия `if(true){}` и `if(false) {}` соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
int main()
{


        sf::RenderWindow wind(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "Window", sf::Style::Default);

        bool draw = true;
        while (wind.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Vector2f rectSize(100,50);
            sf::RectangleShape rect;
            rect.setSize(rectSize);
            rect.setOrigin(rectSize.x/ 2, rectSize.y/2);
            rect.setPosition(wind.getSize().x / 2, wind.getSize().y / 2);
            rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            sf::Event sfEvent;


            while (wind.pollEvent(sfEvent))
            {
                if (sfEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                {
                    wind.close();
                }
                if (sfEvent.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
                {
                    if (sfEvent.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Enter)
                    {
                        draw = !draw;
                    }
                }



            }
            sf::Vector2i pos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(wind);
            float halfX = rectSize.x / 2;
            float halfY = rectSize.y / 2;

            if (draw)
            {
                if (pos.x >= rect.getPosition().x - halfX && pos.x <= rect.getPosition().x + halfX
                    || pos.y >= rect.getPosition().y - halfY && pos.y <= rect.getPosition().y + halfY)
                {
                    std::cout << "Inside" << std::endl;
                }
            }
            wind.clear();
            if (draw)
            {
                wind.draw(rect);
            }
            wind.display();

        }







    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Чувствую без костылей тут не обойтись...